# cakephp find Model instead of read

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I can't load my Model with 'find' but can load that with 'read'. 
I want to get Model attributes by order. But I think 'read' function doesn't have that. How can I use 'find' instead of 'read'?

It works

```
 $itemfiles = $this->Item->read(null, $id);
```

It doesn't work

```
$itemfiles = $this->Item->find('all', array(
                'order' => array('Upload.order' => 'asc'),
                'conditions' => array('Item.id' => $id)
        ));
```

And also is there any way to get data by order using 'read'?

Comment: Is it correct 'order' => array('Upload.order' => 'asc') or 'order' => array('Item.order' => 'asc') ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this like way

```
$itemfiles = $this->Item->Upload->find('all',
    array (
        'conditions'    => array('Item.id' => $id),
        'order'         => array('Upload.order' => 'asc')
    )
);
```